# What do you call this structure or way of coding in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture, structure

I just wanted to clarify something about Angular. A project was turned over to me and I noticed something about the way of implementing it, no scopes, etc. Can anyone explain this code below if what implementation or what do you call this structure in AngularJS? I understand the logic, just want to know if I need to continue this way or not. What can you say about scope vs variable. Or if it's not a good practice, can you please correct it. Is using standard JavaScript a good practice? why?

using standard js

```
 var vm = this;

    vm.title = 'some title';
    vm.saveData = function(){ ... } ;

    return vm;


app.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $controller, JFactory, Notification, $timeout, BtnLoad) {
    var me = this;
    me.current_page = "test page"
    me.ladda = {}
    me.base_url = BASE_URL
    me.record = {
        "is_applicant": true
    }

    me.create = function () {
        var notify = true;
        var url = BASE_URL + "/register/";
        var params = me.record;
        $http.post(url, params)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.status != "200") {
                    return
                }
                me.record = { "is_applicant": true, }
                if (notify) { Notification.success(response.data) }
                BtnLoad.spin.stop()
                console.log("Endpoint :", url, (me.current_page) , response.status)
                JFactory.closeModal('.modal')
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                BtnLoad.spin.stop()
                if (notify) { Notification.error(response.data) }
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would call it : "following John Papa Angular 1 Style Guide".

He recommends to use this syntax over the `$scope` syntax.

If the whole application has been written following his guidelines I strongly recommend you to read his guide.

If not, I still strongly recommend that you read his guidelines because even if you do not agree with everything in this guide, it can still provide some very useful guidance for Angular JS.

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Comment: I'll note here though, if this code was run through a minifier, the function arguments would likely be shortened, and this code would break.

Comment: In his code yes. But if the recommandations from the guide are followed this problem is avoided... https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection